# User Event Script : Alert coming every time the loop iterates

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have been working with the event sublist.
I need to set the values of the attendees using a user event scipt which is deployed for **before load**. This script executes only for the new records created. 
I am able to successfully set the attendee values with other parameters.

**Problem is** when the for loop iterates then every time there is a alert coming saying that  **"Please enter a value for send invitation to"**.

Though the values are set properly but this alert comes as many times as the employees are set as attendee.

Below is the code snippet for the same.

```js
for(var i = 0;i<results.length;i++) {
    var searchresult = results[ i ];
    var record = searchresult.getId();

    nlapiSelectNewLineItem('attendee');

    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('attendee','attendee',record);
    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue("attendee", "response", "NORESPONSE");
    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue("attendee", "attendance", "OPTIONAL");

    nlapiCommitLineItem("attendee");
}
```

May I know how can i make this alert stop?

And one thing : If I deploy this script for **after submit** then it works absolutely fine with no alert. But the business requirement is to run it for before load function.

Thanks
Rahul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the non-dynamic API for working with sublists? Try rewriting your loop as:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var lineIndex = i + 1;

    nlapiSetLineItemValue('attendee','attendee', lineIndex, results[i].getId());
    nlapiSetLineItemValue("attendee", "response", lineIndex, "NORESPONSE");
    nlapiSetLineItemValue("attendee", "attendance", lineIndex, "OPTIONAL");
}
```

Comment: I wish I had a better explanation for *why* this is different, but I am not quite sure unfortunately.